# Combining Calculate, Counta, and Filter returning blank value

Tags: count, powerbi, dax

I am using the Maven Analytics Space Mission dataset. I split up the original Location column for a separate column, Country. I want to create a measure that counts only the rows where the Country column equals "USA", but I can't get the formula to work.

Here is my original formula: Rocket Count USA =

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA(space_missions[Country]),
    FILTER(space_missions, space_missions[Country] IN {"USA"})
)
```

This should return the value 1352, but it returns a blank instead.

I copy and pasted the country name directly from the dataset so it shouldn't be due to case sensitivity or trailing zeroes. The datatype is string. For context, a similar formula using the Company column works as expected so it doesn't seem like an issue with the formula. I was also able to get the expected value of 1352 in Tableau so it doesn't seem like an issue with the underlying data either.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a measure that counts only the rows where the Country
> column equals "USA"

Since you're just counting rows... and you can do simple filters without FILTER(). Where you *need* filter is when you're comparing a column value to a measure. You don't need IN here, because you're only comparing to a single value. (Not to say you couldn't use it)
Your measure can be written more simply in this case... like this

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(space_missions),
    space_missions[Country] = "USA"
)
```